# How to print/show an entire list of objects?

Tags: c++, oop, data-structures

I am following the "Data Structures" book by Michael T. Goodrich. I have no problems following him in the book, but it doesn't teach how to print/show the contents of a list.

I populate my list with objects, all the methods work, but I have no idea how to print/show them on the screen.

```cpp
//list.h

class DLinkedList {                // doubly linked list
  public:
    DLinkedList();                // constructor
    ~DLinkedList();                // destructor
    bool empty() const;                // is list empty?
    const Elem& front() const;            // get front element
    const Elem& back() const;            // get back element
    void addFront(const Elem& e);        // add to front of list
    void addBack(const Elem& e);        // add to back of list
    void removeFront();                // remove from front
    void removeBack();                // remove from back
  private:                    // local type definitions
    DNode* header;                // list sentinels
    DNode* trailer;
  protected:                    // local utilities
    void add(DNode* v, const Elem& e);        // insert new node before v
    void remove(DNode* v);            // remove node v
  };
```

Comment: Do you know how to print a single object? Do you know how to get the next object in the list? Do you know how a loop works? If the answer to these questions is "yes", then you know how to print the list. If the answer to any of these questions is "no", then you should ask that question (and preferably search it first, as for all of these questions there are already answers on SO.)

Comment: @MaxVollmer it tooks me 5 hours but finally i figure it out, i just implement a iterator that beging in the first node of my list, return the value and ends one node before the tail of my list, i apprecitate your response anyway.